# vDos (DOS emulator) shows incorrect character

Tags: ascii, dos, codepages

that is some sort of unusual question. A friend uses an old MS-DOS program on XP to handle some database operations (.dbf files). For instance, the application shows information about product e.g. the diameter. On XP this is displayed like you would expect `Ø 1.2` (maybe not that exact character, but some sort of diameter symbol). But in vDos (runs on Windows 10) `Ý 1.2` is displayed. In the database itself, it is also written `Ý 1.2`. I assume it has something to do with a different codepage or windows graftabl.
If I change the database entry to `Ø` vDos renders it correctly, but this is not the type of solution I am looking for. Do you have any idea what could be different between those two systems and what I could try out?

EDIT: I found a workaround. In vDos it is possible to specify a codepage and change specific characters. Just create a codepage file in the vDos dir (e.g. C_850.txt) and add `chcp 850` to the `autoexec.txt`. Each line in this file represents each char of the 255 chars in the codepage. To swap a char, in my case 237 = `Ý` (line 238) write the hexcode of the char you want to replace it with, in my case `D8` (= `Ø`).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. At least, share database name and version. Please share result of `chcp` command in open `cmd` window (both Windows XP and 10) as well as in an open `vdos` window.  You face a (complex) [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case…

Comment: Sorry, if this question is not fulfilling a mwe. Unfortunately, I cannot have further information, as I do not have access to the system. The database is dBase. I found that they support the usual encodings (437, 850, ...). On W10 and XP 850 is used, on vDos 437.

Comment: Your [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case is (supposedly) as follows: the character `Ø` (U+00D8,  *Latin Capital Letter O With Stroke*) (position `9D` in [`cp850`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)) while at the same position `9D` in the [Kamenický encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamenick%C3%BD_encoding) you can see another character `Ý` (U+00DD,  *Latin Capital Letter Y With Acute*). Nowadays, the *Kamenický encoding* isn't supported (AFAIK) so your workaround seems to be a good approach…

Comment: I forgot to mention, like you did, that D8 is the hex value in unicode. Thank you for your investigation :). Also I was not aware of the term mojibake, so I learned something new. How did you found the correct codepage for the character `Ý`?

Comment: My mother tongue is Czech. Hence, I'm familiar with *Kamenický encoding* as I had been playing in dBase/FoxPro for years (since 1990)… A long-time experience, nothing magic.